# I'm getting the following error trying to debug a Xamarin android project. Note, I have an ios project in the solution too

Tags: java, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.iOS.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5147/c2a33d8e/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 220
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   XCallibre.XForms.Android

Comment: Which line throws this error when you debug? Please post more code about it to help us find the issue.

Comment: thanks, will delete this post. I upgraded the project and everything works now